# Converting a datetime to return only the year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am wanting to take a timestamp and return the year only via SQL. My current sql

```
Convert(varchar(20),IRPBestPracticeTopics.TimeStamp, 106)
```

returns i.e.

```
06 Dec 2012
```

I only want the year to return i.e.

```
2012
```

I know it is the number at the end of the conversion (106), does anyone know what number to put into the end of the conversion to return the year?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has a function called... [`Year()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) !

```
SELECT Year(your_date) As the_year
```

Alternatively there's [`DatePart()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
SELECT DatePart(yy, your_date) As the_year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MySQL/SQL Server:

select YEAR(thetimestampcolumn) from yourtable

Access/SQL Server:

select DatePart(year, thetimestampcolumn) from yourtable

Oracle:

select TO_CHAR(thetimestampcolumn, 'YYYY') from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these,

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) AS YR
SELECT DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()) AS YR
```